# Is a holomorhpic function with these properties the constant $0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose you are given a holomorphic function on $\{Re(z)>0\}$ and such that $f(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$.

Moreover suppose that for any sequence $\{z_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that: $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{\lvert z_k\rvert}{Re(z_k)}\leq C$ for some positive $C$ and $Re(z_k)\to 0$. Then we assume that $f$ satisfy for such a sequence and any $n=0,1,\ldots$:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{k\to\infty} z_k^n\partial_z^nf(z_k)=0,
\end{equation}

where $\partial_z^n$ denotes the nth complex derivative wrt $z$.

Futhermore to avoid trivial counterexamples, we assume that for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$:

\begin{equation}
\limsup_{x\to\infty} \lvert f(x+iy)\rvert\leq D_y,
\end{equation}

for some $D_y>0$.

Is this function constantly $0$?

EDIT: I alpologize for the editing. Explanation with words: I have an olomorphic function defined on the open right half plane which is bounded on horizontal lines and for which radial limits of $f$ and some manipulation of its derivatives at zero are zero. My first, badly posed question was whether or not such a function should be 0, but one can easily understand that $f(z)=z$ is a counterexaples, with any polynomial for which $p(0)=0$. However, my assumption on horizontal lines exclude this easy cases, yielding the question above.

Comment: What is $z_i?$ What values can $n$ take?

Comment: Can you confirm whether the $\limsup$ property is supposed to mean the following?

$$\forall \text{ sequences } z_i,\, \left(\exists C>0,\, \limsup_{i\to\infty}\frac{\lvert z_i\rvert}{Re(z_i)}\leq C\right)\, \implies \, \lim_{i\to\infty} z_i^n\partial_z^nf(z_i)=0$$

I ask because that's what I infer from the way the question is phrased. In particular, where in the statement the part about $C$ should appear is perhaps not so clear.

Comment: I have edited the text. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: Suppose you take $z_k$ to be $1$ for all $k$ (you shouldn't use $i$ for an index in complex analysis). Then you'd be saying $f^{(n)}(1) = 0 $ for all $n$?

Comment: @zhn: good point, however it was my fault not specifying that $z_k$ goes to $0$. I changed indexes too.

Comment: It would be simpler to let $A_\theta= \{re^{it}: r>0, t\in (-\theta,\theta)\}.$ Here $\theta \in [0,\pi/2).$ The main assumption is then $z^nf^{(n)}(z) \to 0$ as $ z\to 0$ within $A_\theta,$ for every such $\theta.$

Comment: Instead of trying to generalize, you should explain your concrete problem. So what is $f$, and what do you know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe $f(z) = e^{-1/z}$ is a counterexample.